# The inner product of cross products.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I need to prove:

$$\langle a \times b | c \times p\rangle = \langle a|c\rangle \langle b|p\rangle - \langle a|p\rangle \langle b|c\rangle$$

$a,b,c,p$ belong to $M$ where $M$ is 3D real inner product space.

Comment: ah so this is called quadruple product. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple_product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(a\times b)\cdot(c\times d)$$

Using the cyclic permutation symmetry of the scalar tripe product,

$$(a\times b)\cdot x=(b\times x)\cdot a.$$

Now replace $x$ with $c\times d$. Using the vector triple product identity,

$$(b\times (c\times d))=c(b\cdot d)-d(b\cdot c).$$

Then,

$$(a\times b)\cdot(c\times d)=(c(b\cdot d)-d(b\cdot c))\cdot a=(c\cdot a)(b\cdot d)-(d\cdot a)(b\cdot c).$$

Answer (score 0):

You just need to show that the left and right hand side are equivalent:

$\langle a,c\rangle\langle b,p\rangle-\langle a,p\rangle\langle b,c\rangle$

$=(a_1c_1+a_2c_2+a_3c_3)(b_1p_1+b_2p_2+b_3p_3)-(a_1p_1+a_2p_2+a_3p_3)(b_1c_1+b_2c_2+b_3c_3)$

Can you do the left hand side?